# Google API throwing 400 error yet display URL OK

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, google-cloud-vision

The program is throwing this 2 errors:

POST https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=APIKEY

EXCEPTION: Response with status: 400 OK for URL:

I did some research regarding this error is that if the enum return is OK for URL means that the URL is OK and return success

source: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/Code

Before i add in the crop feature the API can work however it is throwing me the error here. I am not whether if i declare 2 service class inside a provider in app.components.ts is wrong?.The logic of the program is to take a picture of a list and then the program will bring the user to a crop page where user can crop the image and then the program will pass the image back to the camera.ts page where it will pass the image to the method getVision() which will POST the picture to googleAPI and console.log() the text inside the picture. Below are the codes

```
    @Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',

  providers:[CameraService,TestService]


})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

testing-service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  apiKeys = {
    cloudVision :'ApiKey',

  };

  apiUrls = {
    cloudVision : 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=',

  };


  visionPostObj = {
    requests : [
      {
        image : {
          content : ''
        },
        features: {
          type: 'TEXT_DETECTION',
          maxResults: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }



  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello CameraService Provider');

  }




  getVisionLabels( image : string){

    let url = this.apiUrls.cloudVision + this.apiKeys.cloudVision;
    let post = this.visionPostObj;
    post.requests[0].image.content = image;

    return this.http.post(url, post).map( (res) => res.json());
  }
```

camera.ts

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public testService: TestService,public cameraService: CameraService,public toastCtrl: ToastController) {

  }

    addPhoto(){ 


        this.cameraService.getImage(this.width,this.height,this.quality)
          .subscribe( (data) => {
              this.image = data;
              this.getVision(this.image);
            //console.log(this.image);
            },(error) => {
              // Toast errot and return DEFAULT_PHOTO from Constants
              this.toast(error);
            }
          );
      }

      toast(message: string) {
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: message,
          duration: 2500,
          showCloseButton: false
        });
        toast.present();
      }


      getVision(image64: string) {

      this.testService.getVisionLabels(image64)
        .subscribe((sub) => {

          this.labels = sub.responses[0].textAnnotations;


          this.getText();

        });


    }



    getText() {

      this.labels.forEach((label) => {
        let translation = {search: label.description, result: ''};

            console.log(label.description);

      });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolve the issue already. As the base64 string contains "data:image/jpeg;base64," which in turn will throw this error.Hence i would need to remove that from the base64 string image.

Below are the codes

```
addPhoto(){


    this.cameraService.getImage(this.width,this.height,this.quality)
      .subscribe( (data) => {
          this.image = (data);


          this.imageConvert = this.image.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");

          this.getVision(this.imageConvert);



        },(error) => {
          // Toast errot and return DEFAULT_PHOTO from Constants
          this.toast(error);
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the issue I was facing.